# Excel Interop: Get named table (Range) from specific workbook

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I'm trying to create a WinForms application that interacts with Excel using the Excel Object Library v.15.

I'm using this to get the Excel Application object

```
(Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
```

And I know I can get the Range for the named table I want by using

```
_application.Range["MyTableName"];
```

Now, the problem I'm facing is that if I have two workbooks opened at the same time and each one of them has a named table with the same name, I don't know which Range will be returned.

The Excel application is unique, so I cannot simply try to get the process based on the window title or something like that.
I can get the Workbook object based on its title:

```
_application.Workbooks.Cast<Workbook>().FirstOrDefault(w.Name.Equals(title))
```

However I cannot access the Ranges of a particular Workbook.
I know I could iterate through the Sheets of the Workbook element trying to find the table but I was wondering if there was another "cleaner" way.

I would appreciate any guideline on this.

Thanks,

- Will

Answer (score 0):

The simplest/most direct way I can think of would be to iterate through the [Names collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.names_members.aspx), check the parent, and move on.

E.g:

```
For Each NamedRange as Range in MyApplication.Names
    Dim Check as Object = TryCast(NamedRange.Parent, Workbook)
    If Check Is Nothing Then 
        Check = TryCast(NamedRange.Parent, Worksheet)
        Check = TryCast(Check.Parent, Workbook) 
    End If

    If Not Check Is Nothing AndAlso Check.Name = "MyWorkbook" Then 
        'Do something
    End If
Next
```